# Triple integral of a sphere being cut by a plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the triple integral of: $f(x,y,z)=z(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-3/2}$

Over the part of the ball: $x^2+y^2+z^2\le 16$ with $z\ge 2$

So I converted to spherical coordinates and got: $$f(\rho,\phi,\theta)=\rho cos(\phi)\rho^{-3/2}$$ $$f(\rho,\phi,\theta)=cos(\phi)\rho^{-1/2}$$

Then for the bounds: $$\rho^2\le 16$$ $$\rho\le 4$$ and $$\rho cos(\phi)\ge 2$$ $$2/cos(\phi)\le \rho$$

So: $$2/cos(\phi)\le \rho\le 4$$

Then since the plane crosses the sphere at $z=2$ where $\rho=4$, and $z=\rho cos(\phi)$: $$4cos(\phi)=2$$ $$\phi = \pi/3$$
So: $$0\le\phi\le\pi/3$$
Since it is a sphere I have: $$0\le\theta\le 2\pi$$

So my bounds are:
$$2/cos(\phi)\le \rho\le 4$$
$$2/cos(\phi)\le \rho\le 4$$
$$0\le\theta\le 2\pi$$
Over: $$f(\rho,\phi,\theta)=cos(\phi)\rho^{-1/2}$$

With $dV=\rho^2 sin(\phi)d\rho d\phi d\theta$, I write the integral as:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/3}\int_{2/cos(\phi)}^4 \rho^{-1/2} cos(\phi) \rho^2 sin(\phi) d\rho d\phi d\theta$$

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/3}\int_{2/cos(\phi)}^4 \rho^{3/2} cos(\phi) sin(\phi) d\rho d\phi d\theta$$

Is this all correct?

Comment: You have made a mistake when converting $f$ to spherical coords. $x^2+y^2+z^2\not=\rho$, instead this is $\rho^2$.

Comment: Wow, that makes using spherical coordinates so much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you could set this up in cylindrical coordinates.  The integral becomes

$$2 \pi \int_2^4 dz \, z \: \int_0^{\sqrt{16-z^2}} d\rho \, \rho\, (z^2+\rho^2)^{-3/2}$$

The result I get is $\pi$.

Comment: How would you solve that?

Comment: I did solve it.  Work right to left.  The inner integral may be done by substituting $u=\rho^2$.  The outer integral is then very simple.

Comment: The volume of the sphere before being cut is $4/3 \pi r^3=4/3 \pi *4^3=256 \pi/3$. So we know the top half of the sphere has a volume of half that which is $128 \pi/3$. So $\pi/2$ for that section of the top half seems very small...

Comment: Yeah, but you are not finding a volume, but integrating some function over that volume.

Comment: Oh, forgot that! Let me try this out then.

Comment: I got $\pi$ for my answer.

Comment: You are correct; I dropped a factor of $2$ in my answer.  Good job.

Comment: You're welcome.  Many times, cylindrical coordinates are a better call when you have a situation with axial symmetry like here.  You can still use sphericals, but IMO they are more difficult.

Comment: Actually, CORRECTLY doing spherical here is simple. After the first integral you get the double integral of $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/3}[4cos(\phi)sin(\phi)-2sin(\phi)]d\phi d\theta$.

Comment: In lots of mvc questions here people put the $\rho(z^2+\rho^2)^{-3/2}$ *after* the $\mathrm d\rho$. Why is that? If it is not a constant, shouldn't it be *before* the differential?